# How to copy files from google compute engine to local directory

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to copy files from my instance to my local directory using following command

```
gcloud compute scp <instance-name>:~/<file-name> ~/Documents/
```

However, it is showing error as mentioned below

> $USER/Documents/: Is a directory
>
> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.scp) [/usr/bin/scp] exited with return code [1].

Copying from local directory to GCE works fine.

I have checked Stanford's tutorial and Google's documentation as well.

I have one another instance where there is no issue like this.

I somewhat believe it might be issue with SSH keys.

What might have gone wrong?

Comment: is there a link to the stanford tutorial that you've mentioned?

Comment: And you might as well link to whatever Google documentation you've been reading.

Answer (score 51):

### Your command is correct if your source and destination paths are correct

The command as you've posted in your question works for me when copying a file from the Google Compute Engine VM to my local machine.

```
$ gcloud compute scp vm1:~/.bashrc ~/Documents/
.bashrc                                          100% 3515     3.4KB/s   00:00
```

I also tried doing the copy from other side (i.e. from my local machine to GCE VM) and it works:

```
$ gcloud compute scp ~/Documents/.bashrc vm1:~/temp/
.bashrc                                          100% 3515     3.4KB/s   00:00

$ gcloud compute scp ~/Documents/.bashrc vm1:~/.bashrc-new
.bashrc                                          100% 3515     3.4KB/s   00:00
```

`gcloud` relies on the `scp` executable present in your `PATH`. The arguments you provide to the `gcloud scp` command are passed through to the `scp` binary. Assuming your source and destination paths are correct, it should work.

### Recursive copying using `scp`

Based on your particular error message though, I've seen that variation only appear when the source path you're trying to copy from is a directory instead of file. For that particular case, you can pass a `--recurse` argument (similar to the `-r` argument supported by regular `scp`) which will recursively copy all files and directories under the specified directory.

`gcloud compute scp --recurse SRC_PATH DEST_PATH`

Comment: It appears that the flag is `--recurse`, not `-r` per the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp), and I couldn't get `-r` to work. That's an SSH flag, not a `gcloud compute scp` flag.

Comment: Thanks @MishaBrukman - yes I had the `-r` argument supported by regular `scp`. With `gcloud compute scp` it is `--recurse` instead. Updated the answer.

Comment: How to specify the zone

Comment: @Palsri you can specify zone by --zone=your_instance_zone

Comment: Example scp command to download a file from VM to local system: `gcloud compute scp --zone "europe-west1-c"  --project "projectName" "vmName":/path/to/file/on/vm/301232-PNG.tar.gz  local_file_name.tar.gz`

Answer (score 34):

To copy files from VM to your desktop you can simply SSH into the VM and on top right corner there is a *settings* button, there you will find the *download file* option just enter the path of file.

If it is folder then first zip the folder then download it.

Comment: Had no idea you could do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Everything was perfect except I was trying to run these commands on the terminal connected to GCE instead of local terminal.

```
oyashi@oyashi-torch-instance:~$ gcloud compute scp oyashi-torch-instance:~/spring1617_assignment1.zip ~/Documents/
```

> /home/oyashi/Documents/: Is a directory ERROR: (gcloud.compute.scp)
>   [/usr/bin/scp] exited with return code [1].

But when I tried this one on my local terminal. This happened.

```
oyashi@oyashi:~/Documents$ gcloud compute scp oyashi-torch-instance:~/spring1617_assignment1.zip ~/Documents/
```

> spring1617_assignment1.zip        100%    42KB  42.0KB/s  00:00

Thank you everyone for their comments and help. I know its a silly mistake from my end. But I posted this answer so that others might learn from my silliness.

Answer (score 6):

If you need to pass the information of zone, project name you may like to do as it worked for me:
the instance name is the name you chose in the GCP instances.

```
gcloud beta compute scp --project "project_name" --zone "zone_name" instance_name:~jupyter/file_name /home/Downloads
```

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem. The point is you should run the scp command from a local terminal, rather than cloud terminal.

Answer (score 0):

For copying file to local machine from Ubuntu vmware

For ex: you have instance by name : bhk

Answer (score 0):

Run a basic nginx server and copy all the files in 
 `/var/www/html` (nginx serving dir) 
 and then from your local machine simple run 
 `wget <vm's IP>/<your file path>`

For example If my vm's IP is `1.2.3.4` and I want to copy `/home/me/myFolder/myFile` , then simply copy this file in `/var/www/html`

then run `wget 1.2.3.4/myfile`

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
gcloud compute scp --project "my-project" ./my-file.zip user@instance-1:~
```

**--project** - google cloud project name

**my-file.zip** - local file to send to VM

**user** - vm linux username

**instance-1** - instance name (vm name)

**~** - instance destination path

Answer (score 0):

I use below script to upload directory from local to remote directory

```
gcloud compute scp --recurse myweb-app/www/* user@instant-name:/var/www/html/sub-sites/myweb-app/www/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command to copy the directory from GCP VM to Local:
**gcloud compute scp --recurse --zone "zone-name" VM-name:/tmp/directory or file name . --project "project-id"**
but firstly move the required file to /tmp folder that needs to be copied or scp to local.

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?