# Unable to retrieve file from google cloud instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a google cloud instance that has a program running which creates a file at the end of the run. Now the file that has been created needs to be retrieved to my local machine.
I tried the following commands as per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44982313/how-to-copy-files-from-google-compute-engine-to-local-directory). My command is as follows

`gcloud compute scp root@<instance-name>:~/folder1/folder2/file_name.rds  ~/Documents/`

After entering the password, I get the following error.

`Permission denied (publickey).
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.scp) [/usr/bin/scp] exited with return code [1].`

I have set `Compute Engine` to `Read Write`. Is there anything else I have missed out? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try to run on your command line first:

```
gcloud auth login
```

and then

```
gcloud beta auth application-default login
```

Log in with the google account owner of the project

Comment: The above commands redirected me to a google login page. After that, I ran the same file transfer command and the error persists. I also tried running the file transfer command without logging into the server via SSH. It gave me the same  error `Permission denied (publickey).
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.scp) [/usr/bin/scp] exited with return code [1].` Maybe there are some permission issues?

Comment: Does the account you are log in have permission to access the instance? is it the owner?

Comment: Yes, it does. The account used to create the instance is the owner of the project.

Comment: I don't know what else could be :/, maybe you misspelled the instance name or didn't configure  permissions well

Comment: @adhok, the information provided in this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44982313/how-to-copy-files-from-google-compute-engine-to-local-directory) appeared to be more detailed. I would also like to mentioned as per [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp) that gcloud compute scp does not work for Windows VMs. I was able to follow this [example](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp#EXAMPLES) without any issue. Maybe, try this example in a different VM instance.