# How to copy files from Google Cloud to local machine? (Cloud Shell)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-shell

I spent way too much time trying to figure out how to copy files from the allocated Google Cloud Shell VM to my local machine. The cloud shell is great, but so is having a local copy.

Most of the time was spent trying to get some form of `gcloud compute scp` to work, similar to this syntax:

`$ gcloud compute scp some-instance:~/littlefile.zip ~/`

However in addition to the `compute` command, there is `alpha cloud-shell`!

**Approaches that did not work:**

```bsh
me@mylocalhost:~$ gcloud alpha cloud-shell scp ~/littlefile.zip .
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.cloud-shell.scp) argument (cloudshell|localhost):SRC: Bad value [/home/me/littlefile.zip]: must start with cloudshell: or localhost:
```

```bsh
me@mylocalhost:~$ gcloud alpha cloud-shell scp cloudshell:~/littlefile.zip localhost:~/littlefile.zip
~/littlefile.zip: No such file or directory
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.cloud-shell.scp) [/usr/bin/scp] exited with return code [1].
```

<sub>Mention: [How to copy files from google compute engine to local directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44982313/how-to-copy-files-from-google-compute-engine-to-local-directory) in case others find it but need Cloud Shell commands.</sub>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At the risk of "answering my own question," I actually just solved it! W00T!

**Approaches that did work:**

```bsh
me@mylocalhost:~$ gcloud alpha cloud-shell scp cloudshell:littlefile.zip localhost:.
littlefile.zip            100%   16KB 253.1KB/s   00:00
```

```bsh
me@mylocalhost:~$ gcloud alpha cloud-shell scp cloudshell:littlefile.zip localhost:littlefile.zip
littlefile.zip            100%   16KB 212.1KB/s   00:00
```

```bsh
me@mylocalhost:~$ gcloud alpha cloud-shell scp cloudshell:~/adirectory/still-littlefile.zip localhost:.
still-littlefile.zip      100%   16KB 198.0KB/s   00:00
```