# Download Compressed Folder from Jupyter Notebook in GCloud Deep Learning VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

This seems to be a very simple question, but I couldn't find a way to do it. The jyputer notebook has the option to download file one by one. But my training process generates too many files, and I want to download them all at once. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Actually, I just found a solution to my own question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44982313/how-to-copy-files-from-google-compute-engine-to-local-directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming it is [JupyterLab](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/deep-learning-vm/docs/jupyter) what you are using:

1. Open a new Launcher (+ icon) and start a new terminal session.
2. Use **zip -r FILE_NAME.zip PATH/TO/OUTPUT/FOLDER/** to compress the required folder.
3. Download the zip file as you were doing with the other ones.