# gcloud compute scp does not accept --internal-ip option

Tags: google-cloud-platform, scp

I ran the command:

```
gcp compute scp my_user@10.97.25.64:/opt/myproject/myfile.txt "C:\myfolder" --zone=europe-west2-c --internal-ip
```

The source 10.97.25.64 is a VM instance hosted in GCP. I am trying to copy the file to my local machine "C:\myfolder".

But I always get error:

```
unrecognized argument --internal-ip
```

From the documentation, the --internal-ip is a valid argument. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp. What did I do wrong?

Comment: `--internal-ip` only works if you're in the same vpc as the VM. Are you trying to copy from the VM to your local PC?

Comment: @ZZZ Are you copying files from, or to a Compute Engine VM? Are you trying to copy files from a local machine or another VM in another VPC? Kindly update your question with further details.

Comment: @Puteri I am trying to copy from a GCP-hosted VM to my local machine.

Comment: @JamesS I am trying to copy from a GCP-hosted VM to my local machine.

Comment: Then `--internal-ip` will not work. The doc is very explicit on how this flag works and in what scenarios. Instead use `--tunnel-through-iap`

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @Puteri and also stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp#:%7E:text=Use%20this%20to%20connect%20from%20one%20instance%20to%20another%20on%20the%20same%20VPC%20network%2C%20over%20a%20VPN%20connection%2C%20or%20between%20two%20peered%20VPC%20networks.), the flag `--internal-ip` can only be specified when connecting from one instance to another `on the same VPC network`, `over a VPN connection`, or `between two peered VPC networks`. At this point, my assumption is that the GCP VM isn't connected to your on premise machine through vpn so this doesn't work.

An alternative would be to just `transfer the files using SSH-in-browser` as described in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/transfer-files#download-from-the-vm) and from another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44982313/how-to-copy-files-from-google-compute-engine-to-local-directory#:%7E:text=To%20copy%20files%20from%20VM,the%20folder%20then%20download%20it.)

> To copy files from VM to your desktop you can simply SSH into the VM and on top right corner there is a settings button, there you will find the download file option just enter the path of file.